# Test Angular Service that Returns a $q Promise in Jasmine 2.0 Asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a spec which tests the result of a promise.

The promise resolves, but the `then`, `catch`, and `finally` handlers never seem to fire, and call `done();`

As a result, the spec times out and fails (see screen shot of Chrome Developer Console).

Jasmine suite and spec

```
describe("promise suite", function () {
        var someMethod = function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('All done calling resolve');
                deferred.resolve('all done');
            }, 500);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        iit("promise spec", function (done) {
            someMethod()
                .then(function(message) {
                    console.log('promise method resolved, running expectation');
                    expect(message).toBe('all done');
                    done();
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('promise was rejected ', error);
                    done();
                })
                .finally(function() {
                    console.log('calling done from finally');
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$q promises are resolved on the next digest... so you need to trigger a digest:

```
$rootScope.$digest();
```

Comment: Calling $rootScope.$digest() at the bottom of the spec seems to have no effect.  Is that where you meant to call it from?

Comment: Yes. At the end of the "it".I was convinced that was the issue. I had the same kind of issue recently, and it was a digest issue.

Comment: Although... try calling the digest after resolving your promise (i.e. in your timeout function). That might do it. Again, I'm not sure, I don't have a dev environment on my computer.

Comment: And if that works, maybe try using $timeout instead of setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code in plunkr and it's working, see the console output.

Since there's no app to bootstrap in the example I'm using https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector with the `ng` module to get the `$q` service

http://plnkr.co/edit/pIZ8LVtlyERXVxQB9HI2?p=preview

Comment: I see your code in the plunker, and it's definitely working.  I can't get the same result in my test suite...